# Динамический компонент - db yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу сделать несколько баз данных под `yii2`.
По сути, если используется, допустим, две базы данных, то и в компонентах  прописываются две базы. Но у меня количество баз данных будет расти.
Собственно нужно сделать динамический компонент подключения.
Допустим у меня есть название базы данных, к которой я хочу подключится ("13"), и 
мне нужно динамически обработать компонент подключения, чтобы он на ходу преобразил и подставил id пользователя.
Как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш объект приложения, тот, что наследник от `yii\base\Application`, имеет предка в цепочке наследования класса `yii\di\ServiceLocator`, который отвечает за работу с компонентами приложения.

В момент, когда Вы уже знаете имя базы данных, к которой необходимо подключиться, Вы можете создать ее компонент и сделать его доступным для всего приложения, через унаследованный от прадедушки метод `set()`:

```
Yii::$app->set('dynamicDbConnection', [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=demo', // здесь прописываете доступы к нужной Вам базе
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'charset' => 'utf8',
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-di-servicelocator.html#set%28%29-detail